# If $a,b>0$, find $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ax}-e^{bx}}{(1+e^{ax})(1+e^{bx})}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gre-exam

The question is to find $$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ax}-e^{bx}}{(1+e^{ax})(1+e^{bx})}dx$$
where $a$ and $b$ are positive values. My attempt was to break this up into the sum 
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ax}-e^{bx}}{(1+e^{ax})(1+e^{bx})}dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(1+e^{ax})}dx-\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(1+e^{bx})}dx
$$
and then calculate each individual integral, but I am not sure how to complete the question. It seems like $u$ sub may work, but it was not following easily so I am not sure if this is the best way. Also, as this was taken from a Math GRE practice exam, I am thinking that there may be a trick to this that I am not seeing, so any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Let $u=1+e^{ax}$

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you. As i have worked out the solution from this, should I vote to close?

Comment: I had written out a solution. If you wish to delete, fine. Or you can write out your solution as an answer and I could delete mine.

Comment: Whoops sorry did not see the solution. Accepted it now, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u=e^{ax}$. Then $du=ae^{ax}\,dx$, so our first integral is
$$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{au(u+1)}\,du.$$
We are integrating $\frac{1}{a}\left(\frac{1}{u}-\frac{1}{u+1}\right)$. One antiderivative is $\frac{1}{a}\ln\left(\frac{u}{u+1}\right)$.